# Font Color does not update

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML snippet like this:

```html
    <p align= "left"> <FONT size=3><STRONG> Asset: &nbsp;    </STRONG></FONT><STRONG><FONT color="blue" size=2> something something here  </FONT></STRONG><br> </p>
```

The font color does not seem to work but the font size does change.

Also, I do understand that explicit `font` description is expiring and we should be using the CSS styling. If you could suggest that option,okay to use that option as well.

Comment: Do not use a font tag. It has been deprecated for ages. `<span style="color:red"></span>`, better yet, use a class. Or add the style to the strong tag.

Comment: The `<font>` tag was used in HTML 4

Comment: And HTML tags are usually written in lower case.

Comment: I pasted your code into a snippet and while antiquated, it appears to work. In Chrome and FF at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTML elements and classes is the better option although I do admit some might seem overly complicated.

For my answer, first I give the paragraph a class. Inside of it, I'm aligning the text left and bolding EVERYTHING in it.

Next, spans are by default inline (meaning they show inline with the text, but you don't have control over the spacing). You could also use a div. So every span in the paragraph tag, I'm setting to inline block so I can control the spacing around it while keeping the text inline.

Next each part of the content gets wrapped in its own span.

Since earlier I already set all content to bold, I'm only going to give the title span a margin to the right to space it out and change the font size.

Next for the rest I wrapped that content in another span and changed the color to blue (hex is #Red Green Blue) and I changed the font size also.

```css
.updated{
  text-align:left;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.updated span{
  display:inline-block;
}

.updated .title{
  margin-right:5px;
  font-size:18px;
}

.updated .content{
  color:#0000FF;  
  font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
Originial: <p align= "left"> <FONT size=3><STRONG> Asset: &nbsp;    </STRONG></FONT><STRONG><FONT color="blue" size=2> something something here  </FONT></STRONG><br> </p>

Updated:
<p class="updated">
  <span class="title">Asset:</span>
  <span class="content">something something here</span>
</p>
```

Comment: "Using HTML elements and classes is the better option" — all information such as font size and color, width, height, whether a border is dashed or dotted, is now *removed* from HTML. It can be specified in CSS stylesheets. **It is strongly recommended** to avoid all HTML attributes like `bgcolor` and `align` (which are used in your answer), even though they give the needed effect. To my mind, they gonna be removed completely soon.

Answer (score 2):

Is better to use css:

```
<p style="text-align:center; font-size:14px;"><strong> Asset: &nbsp;</strong><strong  style="color:blue;">something something here</strong><br></p>
```

Comment: thnx. but I want to assign color only to 'Something something here' text.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly. Anyway now you should be autonomous